# Using censusapi to make choropleth map of poverty rates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to creating a choropleth map of poverty by census tract in New Orleans, using the packages censusapi, tigris, and ggplot2. I looked up the following table IDs, using listCensusMetadata(), to get the data that I want:

B17020_001E: Estimate!!Total - POVERTY STATUS IN THE PAST 12 MONTHS BY AGE

B01003_001E: Estimate!!Total - TOTAL POPULATION

These seem right, but when I call these tables, they have almost the exact same values. As a result, it looks like almost every Census tract has 100% poverty. How do I know which tables to use and whether the tables that I am using are correct?

This is my code.

```
#Must sign up for a Census key here in order to access the data: https://api.census.gov/data/key_signup.html

census_api_key("INSERT KEY HERE")
options(tigris_class = "sf")

poverty <- c(poverty = "B17020_001E", 
             population = "B01003_001E")

nola <- get_acs(geography="tract", year=2016, variables= poverty, county = "Orleans", state="LA", geometry=T)

nola_poverty = nola %>% 
  mutate(variable=case_when(
    variable=="B17020_001" ~ "Poverty",
    variable=="B01003_001" ~ "Population")) %>%
  select(-moe) %>% 
  spread(variable, estimate) %>% 
  mutate(percent_poverty=round(Poverty/Population*100,2))

ggplot(nola_poverty) +
  geom_sf(color="#0d394e", size = 0.5, aes(fill=percent_poverty)) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="Blues", direction=1, name="Poverty")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"B17020_001E" in the poverty table refers to total poulation.
So you are essentially dividing total population by total poulation which is why you get 100% for each tract.

"B17020_002E" refers to 'total population with income in the past 12 months below poverty level'.  Further columns refer to poverty by age groups.

So either use,

`poverty <- c(poverty = "B17020_002E", population = "B01003_001E")`

or

`poverty <- c(poverty = "B17020_002E", population = "B17020_001E")`

Both lines will give same data since "B01003_001E" and "B17020_001E" both refer to total population

Comment: view table metadata here :https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs5/groups/B17020.html